# integration of Elmah with aspnetboilerplate

Tags: elmah, aspnetboilerplate

I can see that ABP logs all errors in the log.txt file in the but wonder if there is any tutorial that explains how to add ELMAH to the Boilerplate template?

I am using Asp core + Angular template. I have already installed Elmah to my solution but not quite sure how to integrate `AbpHandledExceptionData` with it.

Here are my settings:

```
//ELMAH
services.AddElmahIo(o =>
{
    o.ApiKey = _appConfiguration["Authentication:Elmah:APIKey"];
    o.LogId = new Guid(_appConfiguration["Authentication:Elmah:LogId"]);
});
```

Comment: Please read on [ask]

Comment: FYI, you have added elmah.io and not ELMAH to your project. ELMAH (open source project) doesn't support ASP.NET Core yet, but elmah.io (commercial product) does. Correct me if I'm wrong, but it sounds to me like you want to use ELMAH and not elmah.io (elmah.io is a paid product also doing error logging but besides that very different from ELMAH).

Answer (score 1):

You can refer [Logging from ASP.NET Core](https://docs.elmah.io/logging-to-elmah-io-from-aspnet-core/). Another option similar to ELMAH (and ELM) is Glimpse: http://getglimpse.com/

You can also use [ASP.NET Core Diagnostics](https://github.com/aspnet/Diagnostics) for the same purpose.